# Circle in bi-matrix (game theory)

Tags: circles

How can I draw a circle around the payoffs in the matrix? An is there a way to align the payoffs within the matrix?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{game}{2}{2}[Player 1][Player 2]
        &  C      &  D     \\
     C  &  $25, 2.5$ & $0.01, 30$  \\
     D  &  $2.5, 30$ & $1, 1$\\
\end{game}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you please add a sketch of the desired output?

Comment: Hi, the only thing I want is to draw a circle around a number (payoff) within the matrix. For instance around 25.

Comment: You should take look at the `circledsteps` package.

Comment: That's great! Thank you Bernard. Do you know how to get a thicker line? It doesn't say in the package description.